# Is there a way to use script filelds calculation on filters using elasticsearch or opensearch API?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, searchkick

I have an elasticsearch query that calculates price using script fileds. However I want to filter using calculated value but I cannot access it on script query. Is there a way I could use script field in filters?

I am using searchkick gem on ruby on rails app. I have following query for search

```
{
  script_fields: {
    total_stay_fee: {
      script: {
        source: "
          def totalStay = params.total_stay;
          def defaultRate = params['_source']['default_rate'];

          return totalStay * defaultRate;
        ",
        params: {
          total_stay: 12
        }
      }
    }
  },
  _source: ["*"],
  query: {
    function_score: {
      query: {
        bool: {
          filter: {
            range: {
              total_stay_fee: {
                gte: 12,
                lte: 100
              }
            }
          },
        }
      },
      boost_mode: "replace",
      score_mode: "first"
    }
  }
}
```

I have calculated value of `total_stay_fee`, however I want to filter result based on it's value. How do I achieve that?

Also, worth noting `defaultRate` is dynamic, so I cannot really index and use that either.

Comment: You take `defaultRate` from the `_source` so it's indexed... Did you mean the `total_stay` paramater is dynamic ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the most effective way would be to just divide values in `gte` and `lte` by 12 and compare with `defaultRate`.

However, assuming that you have a more complicated equation you can use `script` query. You cannot use `_source` in the script query because it will negatively affect performance on large datasets, but you can use doc values instead.

```
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "default_rate": {
        "type": "double"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_bulk?refresh
{"index":{}}
{"default_rate":0.5}
{"index":{}}
{"default_rate":1}
{"index":{}}
{"default_rate":5}
{"index":{}}
{"default_rate":7}
{"index":{}}
{"default_rate":10}

POST test/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "total_stay_fee": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          def totalStay = params.total_stay;
          def defaultRate = params['_source']['default_rate'];

          return totalStay * defaultRate;
        """,
        "params": {
          "total_stay": 12
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "*"
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": """
                 def totalStay = params.total_stay;
                 def defaultRate = doc['default_rate'].value;
                 def total_stay_fee = totalStay * defaultRate;
                 return total_stay_fee >=  params.gte && total_stay_fee <=  params.lte;
              """,
              "params": {
                "total_stay": 12,
                "gte": 12,
                "lte": 100
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @imotov, thank you for your comment. I tried the way you suggested but I am getting following error
"No field found for [default_rate] in mapping"
Could you please suggest what I might have missed?

Comment: Did you try running my code in entirety and got this error?

Comment: Oh I see, you probably tried running it on your index where default_rate is not indexed. You need to index that. `_source` is not accessible in the search context, so you can only access indexed fields there (or runtime fields that are calculated from indexed fields)

Comment: Ah okay. That worked for default_rate. The error was from other field which is a nested_field. Can we access nested field from above script query?

Comment: Also, can I access runtime fields from the script query? I have calculated the value of total_price in the script query. It's a complex calculation. How do I access its value on the script query filter?

Comment: Search has 2 phases - "query" and "fetch". During the query phase the script filter is used to find top hits, this happens on every shard in the index (possibly on different nodes). Shards then send ids + sort keys of top hits to the coordinating node, which merges them, then coordinating node is sending "fetch" requests to all shards with a list of final top hits. During this phase, the script fields are calculated. So, filter cannot access scripted fields because it is executed before them and scripted fields cannot access results of the filter because only IDs and sort keys are preserved.

Comment: TLDR: you will have to calculate them twice unless you can stash the results in the _score. To answer the question about nested field I need to see the mapping and the query. Preferably in another question since it is a completely different topic for discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the response @imotov. I have added another question as suggested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77399452/how-do-i-iterate-over-indexed-data-in-script-filter-query-using-elasticsearch